# Simple circuit with mesh current. Two resistors, two batteries

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image: ECE302]

I can't find current through 6k resistor using mesh-current method.

Using KVL on left and right side you get:

\begin{align}
V_\text{4k} + V_{6k} - 10V =& 0 \tag{left loop}\\
13V \text{(voltage across 4k)} + V_{6k} - 10V =& 0 \\
3V =& - V_{6k}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
3V - V_{6k} =& 0 \tag{right loop} \\
3V =& - V_{6k}
\end{align}

So using KVL, the current across the 6K is $3V/6\text{k}\Omega = 0.5\,\text{mA}$.

However, if I try mesh-current method, I get

\begin{align}
-10 + 13 + 6K (i_1 - i_2) =& 0 \tag{left side} \\
i_2 =& \frac{3+6000 i_1}{6000}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
3+6K(i_1-i_2) =& 0 \tag{right side}
\end{align}

Substituting $ i_2 = (3+6000 i_1)/(6000)$ to the right side, I don't get an answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think the voltage across the 4k resistor is 13 V?

Comment: @ThePhoton well, isn't that simple? Before 4k resistor, voltage is 10V, on the right side of 4k resistor voltage comes from the right battery, which supplies 3V. So the difference in voltages is the voltage across 4k resistor, no?

Comment: If point A is at 10 V and point B is at 3 V, the difference between them is 7 V, not 13 V. You even got this correct in the calculation shown in the image (where you wrote $i_D = \frac{10-3}{4k}$).

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're going to use the mesh current method, you don't start with any knowledge of the voltage across the 4k resistor. Instead you just use 
   $$v_{4k} = i_{D1}(4 \rm{k\Omega})$$
2. The voltage across the 4k resistor is not 13 V, it's 7 V, like you correctly calculated in the equation for $i_{D1}$ to the right of your schematic.

Comment: But I thought it'd be considered to be negative, as in 10 - (-3) = 13V. Because according to passive sign convention, + is on the left side of the 4k resistor, while minus is on the right side... or maybe I'm confusing it with the current flow...

Comment: The battery direction is defined by the longer of the two lines in the battery signal.